# UDP Chat In Java

Tags: java, sockets, udp, chat

I am trying to create a a client and server chat program using UDP. I have followed a tutorial making a similar program using TCP and tried to then translate my knowledge over to make one in similar fashion using UDP.

I have completed a client and server side with both showing no errors and will run, but once running neither will message the other or receive messages... can someone help me see what i'm doing wrong?

Server side for sending messages:

```
try{
        //creates the packet to be sent
        byte[] buf = new byte[256];
        String msgout = serverText.getText().trim();
        buf = msgout.getBytes();

        //uses the socet.receive method to get the packet to retrieve information to send
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
        ss.receive(packet);
        InetAddress address = packet.getAddress();
        int port = packet.getPort();

        //uses packet information to create and send packet
        DatagramPacket packetSend = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, address, port);
        ss.send(packetSend);

        //Displays the message in the chat area and clears the text area
        serverArea.setText(serverArea.getText().trim()+"\n Server: "+msgout);
        serverText.setText("");

    }catch (Exception e){

    }
```

and then the main for setting the socket and receiving/printing:

```
String msgin = "";
    try{

        ss = new DatagramSocket(1420); // Sets socket at 1420
        byte[] buf = new byte[256];
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
        ss.receive(packet); //Receives the packet from the socket


        //Converts the byte array into a string
        String clientMsg = new String(packet.getData(), 0, packet.getLength());

        while(!msgin.equals("exit")){
            //Displays the message
            msgin = clientMsg;
            serverArea.setText(serverArea.getText().trim()+"\n Client: "+msgin); //displays client message

        }

    }catch(Exception e){

    }
```

Here is the client side code, ill combine its send and receive areas into one block:

```
try{
        //Creates the message out using the known socket that the Server creates and the known local address
        String msgout = clientText.getText().trim();
        sendBuf = msgout.getBytes();
        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        DatagramPacket sp = new DatagramPacket(sendBuf, sendBuf.length, address, 1420);
        s.send(sp);

        //Displays the text and clears the text field
        clientchat.setText(clientchat.getText().trim()+"\n Server: "+msgout);
        clientText.setText("");


    }catch (Exception e){

    }
String msgin = "";

    try{
        //Creates a socket
        DatagramSocket s = new DatagramSocket();

        //Receives the message from the server
        byte[] buf = new byte[256];
        DatagramPacket rp = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
        s.receive(rp);

        //Converts byte array to message
        String clientMsg = new String(rp.getData(), 0, rp.getLength());

        while(!msgin.equals("exit")){
            //Displays the message
            msgin = clientMsg;
            clientchat.setText(clientchat.getText().trim()+"\n Server: "+msgin); //displays client message

        }


    }catch (Exception e){

    }
```

Any help and tips will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you have empty catch blocks, of course you won't see errors.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing is happening, and you are unable to send/receive messages, it is likely that there are exceptions that are being generated.

However, since you have a try-catch block that catches all exceptions, and then simply does nothing, you will have no idea what exceptions are thrown, if any are thrown at all.

Rather than simply ignoring exceptions, you should at least be printing their cause.

In your catch statements, add the following and you will be able to more easily debug.

```
e.printStackTrace();
```

Comment: unfortunately this hasnt done anything to my program and it still does nothing. im going to just have to scrap it i suppose and try to start from new.